# Why doesn't my interface have the methods the JLS says it declares?

Tags: java, methods, reflection, language-lawyer

Reading this [part](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.2) in JLS:

> If an interface has no direct superinterfaces, then the interface implicitly declares a public abstract member method m with signature s, return type r, and throws clause t corresponding to each public instance method m with signature s, return type r, and throws clause t declared in Object, unless a method with the same signature, same return type, and a compatible throws clause is explicitly declared by the interface.

I tried to confirm the existence of these methods through reflection, but only the `ok` method shows up.

Why aren't the implicitly declared methods showing up? How can I see them?

```
interface C {
    public void ok();
}
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (Method m : C.class.getMethods()) {
            System.out.println(m.getName()+":"+Modifier.isAbstract(m.getModifiers()));
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
ok:true
```

Comment: Instantiate a `C` instance, and look at its' methods. Or call `toString` on a `C` instance. `C c = new SubC(); System.out.println(c.toString());`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: That doesn't do anything to demonstrate the existence of the implicit `public abstract` method declarations.

Comment: I think this is either an implementation bug or a JLS defect.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch,  I agreee with user2357112 . If i apply the code to class ,  it will print Object methods in the reflect.Methods

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JLS is accurate, but you've made an incorrect assumption about what [`Class.getMethods()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethods--) returns:

> Returns an array containing `Method` objects reflecting all the public methods of the class or interface represented by this `Class` object, including those declared by the class or interface and those inherited from superclasses and superinterfaces.
>
> ...
>
> If this `Class` object represents an interface then the returned array does not contain any implicitly declared methods from `Object`. Therefore, if no methods are explicitly declared in this interface or any of its superinterfaces then the returned array has length 0.

Comment: On one hand, yeah, that's reasonable. I overlooked that part of the documentation. On the other hand, `Class.getDeclaredMethods` doesn't have any such text in its Javadoc, but it shows the same behavior (and it includes bridge methods in its output, so I would expect these methods to count too). Doc defect? I suspect `Class.getMethod` and `Class.getDeclaredMethod` would behave the same, though I haven't tested it.

Comment: @user2357112 [`Class.getDeclaredMethods()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethods--) *never* returns inherited methods, and it's also clearly documented: *Returns an array containing `Method` objects reflecting all the declared methods of the class or interface represented by this `Class` object, including public, protected, default (package) access, and private methods, but excluding inherited methods.*

Comment: But these aren't inherited.

Comment: So, I do not have a way to get all the methods of an interface ? Or I could assume every interface will have Object's methods implicitly (assume no override).

Comment: You could get them from Object separately.